# By default, bc interprets any alpha character as a 9

Tags: bash, bc

**System**:

- Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS
- GNU bash, version 5.1.16(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
- bc 1.07.1

**Observation**:

Both `ibase` and `obase` are unset.

```
echo "A0" | bc
90
echo "B0" | bc
90
echo "X0" | bc
90
```

**Question**:
Why does `bc` interpret alpha characters as `9`s by default? Why wouldn't an error message be preferable here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From `man bc` on a GNU system (with GNU `bc` 1.07 or newer):

> A simple expression is just a constant. `bc` converts constants into internal decimal numbers  using  the  current  input  base, specified by the variable `ibase`. (There is an exception in functions.)  The legal values of `ibase` are 2 through 36. (Bases greater than 16 are  an  extension.)
> Assigning  a value outside this range to `ibase` will result in a value of 2 or 36.  Input numbers may contain the characters 0-9 and A-Z. (Note: They must be capitals.  Lower  case  letters  are variable  names.)   Single  digit  numbers  always have the value of the digit regardless of the value of `ibase`. (i.e. A = 10.)  For **multi-digit numbers**, `bc` changes all input digits greater  or equal to `ibase` to the value of `ibase-1`.  This makes the number `ZZZ` always be the largest 3 digit number of the input base.

(Emphasis mine.)